# Missing bytes sended through serial from C# app

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c#

I am trying to store values sended by C# app in EEPROM via Arduino UNO. Here is a C# code that reads bytes from file (I'm 100% sure that there are, and always will be 256 bytes) and sends the buffer via SerialPort

```
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        const string fileName = @"filepath";
        port.Open();
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        port.Write("W");
        port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Here is Arduino Code

```
int flag;
int datasize = 256;
byte byteBuffer[256];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //read_write();
}


void loop() {
  readEEPROM();
  writeEEPROM();
  delay(500);
}

void readEEPROM() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    flag = Serial.read();
    if (flag == 'R') {
      for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
        byteBuffer[i] = ME.read(i);
      }
      flag = 'S';
      Serial.write(byteBuffer, datasize);
    }
  }
}
void writeEEPROM() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    flag = Serial.read();
    if (flag = 'W') {
      int bytesRead = 0;
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      while (bytesRead < 256) {
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
          byteBuffer[bytesRead] = Serial.read();
          bytesRead++;
        }
      }
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(50);
    ME.writeEnable();
    ME.write(i, byteBuffer[i]);
    ME.writeDisable();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(50);
  }
  flag = 'S';
   }
  }
 }
```

As you can see in `writeEEPROM` function arduino turns on `BUILTIN_LED` before it starts reading serial, sadly the LED is never turning off, which makes me think like there are never 256 bytes in SerialPort, whats more, when i turn the c# program on again, the arduino successfully leaves the while loop, but the data is deformed, I mean the values are different.

Comment: why don't you know if there are 256 bytes received by the serial port?

Comment: Don't forget that the Arduino reboots every time you open the serial port from the computer - and the bootloader runs for a second or two gobbling up any serial data you send its way...

Comment: @jsotola Well, to leave the while loop arduino needs to enter into `if(Serial.available())` 255 times, right now it is not leaving while loop, that's why i assume that there are couple of bytes missing or something like that :/

Comment: @Majenko How can I solve this then ? :)

Comment: Either put a delay after opening the serial port to give the bootloader a chance to finish, or write a proper protocol that includes being able to tell if the Arduino is ready to receive data.  Maybe send a "?" and if the Arduino replies "Y" then it's running and you can send data.

Comment: But if the arduino comes into Flag = 'W' in my example isn't it already able to read the data? I mean it have to read the serial to start the function :) Anyway I tried delaying the C# program after opening the port, it didn't help

Comment: It can't help but get into "w" - you're assigning with `=` not comparing with `==`.

Comment: @Shizzle, the reason i asked you why you do not know if 256 bytes have been received was to make you think "how do i verify that 256 bytes have been sent without error?" .... you can debug your code by removing the EEPROM code and replacing it with code that sends the data back to sender ... that way you can narrow down the area of failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two basic things wrong here.

First is your way of opening the serial port and immediately sending data.  The Arduino is reset when you open the serial port and the bootloader runs. This takes a second or so, and during that time any data that you send is lost.

Secondly you're not checking for a flag of "W" but instead you're assigning "W" to the flag, which always succeeds.

The line

```
if (flag = 'W') {
```

should read

```
if (flag == 'W') {
```

To get around the first problem you can either just put a delay (however you do that in C#) after opening the port and before sending the "W", or you could implement a "Are you there?" handshake to look for the Arduino.

One example would be to add an extra flag of (say) "?" to which the Arduino simply responds "Y".

The PC then sends "?" and, if it doesn't receive "Y" within a certain timeout it loops sending "?" again.

Once it receives "Y" then it knows the Arduino is there and ready to receive data, so you can send the "W" command and the data.